# Could not find or load main class error in cmd with source code from princeton

Tags: java

I download source code from here http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/code/

My folder contains three files: algs4.jar, java file and input txt file.
When I type this command line in cmd

```
javac -cp .;algs4.jar JavaFile.java
```

It's ok.
But then, I type

```
java -cp .;algs4.jar JavaFile.java InputFile.txt
```

That don't work. It has an error: "Could not find or load main class ..". 
Can somebody help me ? :)

Comment: Where is the location of `JavaFile.java`?  You changed your question after I answered it.

Comment: Which source code did you down load?  Does the .java file actually contain a `main` method?

Comment: I download ThreeSum.java, algs4.jar and 1Kints.txt. Yes, it has

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `JavaFile.java` has a `main` method use

```
java -cp .;algs4.jar JavaFile InputFile.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

int the manifest of algs4.jar do not assign the main class, so you use -cp option to point it out, but the main class should have a **full name**, including the **full package name**.such as:

```
java -cp algs4.jar edu.princeton.cs.algs4.AcyclicLP
```

Comment: Is there no way to do it without the full name? The instructor seems to execute directly - `java ThreeSum 4000 4Kints.txt`, but I can't find a way to..